# Using ImportXML to pull data

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula

Trying to scrape the data - the number of the subscribers

with this formula - =IMPORTXML(A2,"//a/@href[contains(., подписчиков')]")

Since the coding is the anchored text
[image]

Unfortunately it does not work for me.
Here is the link to the spreadsheets https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QE3G7wvIfYC9AagAfb8TPYR9_9Yi4hchWtLmNBc8t4I/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please share all your relevant code including the link to the page you are working on

Comment: I added all the data to the spreadsheets.

Comment: There is no code there, only a link to some blog page

Comment: I am trying to scrape the data from this link with =IMPORTXML(A2,"//a/@href[contains(., подписчиков')]") , I don't have any special code.

Comment: Where is you scraping code? Selenium / BS4?

Comment: simply using formula, no code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241536/discussion-between-hanna-and-prophet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page is generated by Javascript (You can see it when you disable javascript in your browser - only blank page will be displayed).

Importxml can't scrape any data from this kind of webpage.

This is how it looks with javascript switched off.

[image]